# Is there a way to get static ip address for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have to transfer data from an on-premise sql server to Azure Sql using Azure Data Factory however sql server owner needs to whitelist the public IP's to provide access to their service. I know that there is a range of IP's that are used by ADF in specific regions but is there a way to set one static IP which not gonna change and which I will be able to provide to my client ?

Comment: This is nornally achieved by using a self hosted runtime. Don't ever open your SQL Server up to the internet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#ports-and-firewalls

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/azure-data-factory-now-supports-static-ip-address-ranges/ba-p/1117508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly mentioned by Nick and wBob, you can get IP addresses that your Azure Integration Runtime uses but that is same for all in the same region and not unique Static IP address for only your integration runtime as Azure Integration Runtime is serverless. You have to set up a self-hosted integration runtime to get a Static IP for Data Factory connectors.

Also checkout simialr [Copy data securely from Azure Blob storage to a SQL database by using private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private)

Comment: Okay so as I understand I need to create a self-hosted IR and set it up on the on-premise machine, right ? 
Where I will be able to find my static ip then?

Comment: once you setup, ADF studio --> Manage --> Integration Runtimes --> Select your SHIR --> nodes tab --> IP address

Comment: If you set up an on-premises server, it may or may not have a static IP (depending on configuration). But regardless your network people should be far happier about opening traffic to an on-premises machine. BTW, it doesn't need to be on premise, the VM could be in Azure